# "Boltzmann" equation for radiation (Reheating period)

Tags: cosmology, field-theory, cosmological-inflation, boltzmann-equation

These equations are given in many papers as the "Boltzmann equations" (without derivation) governing the reheating period, where $\rho_\phi$ is the energy density of the decaying inflaton field and $\rho_R$ is the energy density of the light particles it decays to.
$$\dot{\rho_\phi}+3H\rho_\phi= -\Gamma_\phi\rho_\phi,$$

$$\dot{\rho_R}+4H\rho_R=\phantom -\Gamma_\phi\rho_\phi,$$

$$H^2=\dfrac{1}{3M_P^2}(\rho_\phi+\rho_R).$$
In what sense are these Boltzmann equations? I am particularly asking for the first and the second equations. Can this be derived from the Boltzmann equation I am familiar with:
$$\frac{df}{d\lambda}=C[f;f]$$
$$p^0\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}-Hpp^0 \frac{\partial f}{\partial p}=C[f;f]$$
If so, then how?

---

EDIT:
I was not being too bright when thinking about this, and I figured later that I am supposed to take moments of $f$ to get the transport equations for energy density and other quantities. The equation for radiation energy density comes out right, because $p^0=p$ for light (massless) particles. But for the heavy particles,
$$\dot \rho -H\int (p)^3 \sqrt{(p)^2+m^2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial p}(4\pi) dp$$
while integrating by parts,
$$\frac{d}{d p} ((p)^3 \sqrt{(p)^2+m^2})=3(p)^2 E + \frac{(p)^4}{E} $$
The first term gives me what I want. Is it reasonable to take the second term as $0$ because $p<<E$?